# Header and Footer Rows get resized by content

Tags: html, css, angular-material

in this little example I have two bars (header/bottom) which should have a specific height of 175 px. Between them I would like to have some cards. Fine, it worked for a couple of cards. But, as more cards as I add, the bars get shrinked to a smaller size.

```
[http://codepen.io/n00n/pen/bBZKwb][1]
```

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: @noon I'm added an answer below,don't forget to tick it if it's useful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **min-height**,it will preserve your height

in this code add **min-height:175px;** to your **#PageHeader, #PageBottom** it will works fine.,,I'm added the snippet below.

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body{
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body#index{
    background-image: url("../assets/start-page.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.body-row{
    display: table-row;
}

.body-cell{
    display: table-cell;
}

#TopLogo, #TopNavigation, #BottomInformation, #BottomNavigation{
    color: #F1BF00;
}

#TopLogo{
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}

#TopNavigation{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}

#PageHeader, #PageBottom{
    position: relative;
    background: #AA151B;
    height: 175px;
  min-height:175px;
}


#PageBottom{
    position: relative;
}

#BottomInformation{
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    height: 175px;
    line-height: 175px;
}

#BottomNavigation{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 10px;
}

#PageContent {
    background: #F1BF00;
}

#CardColumn{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#PageContent .body-cell{
    padding: 10px;
}

.rightAlign{
    text-align: right;
}

a{
    color: #FFFF00;
    margin: 5px;
}

#contentframe{

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    body#index{
        background-image: url("../assets/start-page-smart.jpg");
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
}

#wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    min-width: 800px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

#columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 15px;
    column-fill: auto;
}

.pin {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #FEFEFE;
    border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
    margin: 0 2px 15px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}

.pin img {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.pin p {
    font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
    #columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
    #columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 5;
        -moz-column-count: 5;
        column-count: 5;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1920px) {
    #columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 7;
        -moz-column-count: 7;
        column-count: 7;
    }
    #wrapper {
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 2200px;
        min-width: 1600px;
        margin: 50px auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/cards.css">


        <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Angular Material Library -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            /**
             * You must include the dependency on 'ngMaterial'
             */
            angular.module('EspanioApp', ['ngMaterial']);


        </script>

    </head>

    <body ng-app="EspanioApp" layout="row" flex>

        <div layout="column" flex>

            <div layout="row" id="PageHeader">
                <div id="TopLogo">das Logo fehlt</div>
                <div id="TopNavigation">das Menü fehlt</div>
            </div>



            <!-- https://mikethedj4.github.io/Webkit-Scrollbar-Generator/ -->
            <div layout="row" id="PageContent" flex>

                <div layout="column" id="CardColumn" flex>

                    <div id="wrapper">

                        <div id="columns">

                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>
                            <div class="pin"><img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" /><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.</p></div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div layout="row" id="PageBottom">
                <div id="BottomInformation">das Impressum </div>
                <div id="BottomNavigation">das untere Menü fehlt</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>









</html>
```

Comment: Fine... That works. But why did it ignore my height? So if I like to fix I always need to set min-height and max-height ?